# I need to ignore all errors in Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have special template for traversing in Razor. Template is migrated from PHP and 100% works. Bud Razor shows error:

> Encountered end tag "li" with no matching start tag.  Are your start/end tags properly balanced?

Can I force ignore start/end tags?

My code:

```
<ul id="filter">

    @{ 
        List<Nipo.Models.Entity.category_path> CategoryPaths = ViewData["Categories"] as List<Nipo.Models.Entity.category_path>;
        Nipo.Models.Entity.category CurrentCategory = ViewData["Category"] as Nipo.Models.Entity.category;
        Dictionary<int, List<int>> Parents = ViewData["Parents"] as Dictionary<int, List<int>>;
        int Counter = 0;
    }

    @foreach (var CategoryPath in CategoryPaths)
    {
        Nipo.Models.Entity.category_path Next = CategoryPaths[Counter + 1];
        bool IsActive = (CurrentCategory != null && CurrentCategory.id_category == CategoryPath.category.id_category);

        <li class="if(IsActive) { active }">
            <a title="CategoryPath.category.name">
                CategoryPath.category.name
                <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
            </a>


            if (Next != null && Next.depth > CategoryPath.depth)
            {
                <ul class="collapse if (IsActive) { in } if (Parents[CategoryPath.category.id_category] != null && CurrentCategory != null && Parents[CategoryPath.category.id_category].Contains(CurrentCategory.id_category)) { style="display: block" })
            }else if (Next != null && Next.depth < CategoryPath.depth)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < (CategoryPath.depth - Next.depth); i++)
                {
                    </ul></li>
                }
            }else if (Next != null && Next.depth == CategoryPath.depth)
            {
                </li>
            }else if(Next == null)
            {
                for(var i = 0; i < CategoryPath.depth; i++)
                {
                    </ul></li>
                }
            }
    }

</ul>
```

Comment: Why can't you put the last ```</li>``` at the bottom of the code and balance it out? I know you said you ported it over from PHP, but sometimes code needs to be fixed.

Comment: I try it tomorrow ;-)

Comment: Not helped. Same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final:

```
<ul id="filter">

    @{ 
        List<Nipo.Models.Entity.category_path> CategoryPaths = ViewData["Categories"] as List<Nipo.Models.Entity.category_path>;
        Nipo.Models.Entity.category CurrentCategory = ViewData["Category"] as Nipo.Models.Entity.category;
        Dictionary<int, List<int>> Parents = ViewData["Parents"] as Dictionary<int, List<int>>;
        int Counter = 0;
    }

    @foreach (var CategoryPath in CategoryPaths)
    {


        Nipo.Models.Entity.category_path Next = CategoryPaths.ElementAtOrDefault(Counter+1);
        bool IsActive = (CurrentCategory != null && CurrentCategory.id_category == CategoryPath.category.id_category);

        if (IsActive)
        {
            @Html.Raw("<li class=\"active\">")
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.Raw("<li>")
        }

        <a title="@CategoryPath.category.name">
            @CategoryPath.category.name
            <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </a>


        if (Next != null && Next.depth > CategoryPath.depth)
        {

            string Class = "";
            string Style = "";
            string Element = "<ul class=\"collapse ";

            if (IsActive)
            {
                Element += "in ";
            }

            Element += "\" ";

            if (Parents.ContainsKey(CategoryPath.category.id_category) && CurrentCategory != null && Parents[CategoryPath.category.id_category].Contains(CurrentCategory.id_category))
            {
                Element += "style=\"display: block\" ";
            }

            @Html.Raw(Element)

        } else if (Next != null && Next.depth < CategoryPath.depth)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < (CategoryPath.depth - Next.depth); i++)
            {
                    @Html.Raw("</ul></li>");
                }
            }
            else if (Next != null && Next.depth == CategoryPath.depth)
            {
                @Html.Raw("</li>");
            }
            else if (Next == null)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < CategoryPath.depth; i++)
                {
                    @Html.Raw("</ul></li>");
                }
        }
        Counter++;
    }
```

Thanx for all

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, Go to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Html -> Validation and turn it off.

Comment: It is not problem of Editor validation. I get this error in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `@Html.Raw` method to insert strings with no validation whatsoever.  Obviously you can't use Razor-specific tricks here.

Or, more simply, move the closing tag to the end since it's repeated in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@:` in front of the tags

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to output the strings Raw, instead of as part of Razor, like this:

```
@foreach (var CategoryPath in CategoryPaths)
{
    Nipo.Models.Entity.category_path Next = CategoryPaths[Counter + 1];
    bool IsActive = (CurrentCategory != null && CurrentCategory.id_category == CategoryPath.category.id_category);

    <li class="if(IsActive) { active }">
        <a title="CategoryPath.category.name">
            CategoryPath.category.name
            <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </a>


        if (Next != null && Next.depth > CategoryPath.depth)
        {
            <ul class="collapse if (IsActive) { in } if (Parents[CategoryPath.category.id_category] != null && CurrentCategory != null && Parents[CategoryPath.category.id_category].Contains(CurrentCategory.id_category)) { style="display: block" })
        }else if (Next != null && Next.depth < CategoryPath.depth)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < (CategoryPath.depth - Next.depth); i++)
            {
                </ul>
                @Html.Raw("</li>")
            }
        }else if (Next != null && Next.depth == CategoryPath.depth)
        {
            @Html.Raw("</li>")
        }else if(Next == null)
        {
            for(var i = 0; i < CategoryPath.depth; i++)
            {
                </ul>
                @Html.Raw("</li>")
            }
        }
}
```

However, I would strongly recommend that you embrace the Razor syntax, and re-write the page to make this work the "right" way. It looks like you're trying to create a nested list based on a recursive structure. If that's the case, instead of having a bunch of confusing `if/else` blocks and `for` loops, you could just create a `@helper` function that calls itself recursively. This approach will almost undoubtedly produce cleaner, less error-prone code.